# Llamar a una función de un grupo a partir de un listado con sus nombres en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de invocar una serie de funciones JS basandome en sus nombres que guardo como strings en un array.

Código de prueba:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main class="content">
        <h2>Prueba "callbacks"</h2>

        <section class="button-group right-content top-2">
            <h3 hidden>Botones de acción</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="activate">Activate</button>
            <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="deactivate">Deactivate</button>

            <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="disable">Disable</button>
            <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="enable">Enable</button>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            'use strict';

            const buttonActions = [
                'activate',
                'deactivate',
                'disable',
                'enable',
            ];
            for (let index = 0; index < buttonActions.length; index++) {
                const action = buttonActions[index];
                const selector = 'button[data-action="' + action + '"]';

                const callback = getCallbackFunc(action);
                const button = document.querySelector(selector)
                    .addEventListener('click', callback);
            }
            function getCallbackFunc(action)
            {
                if (action === 'activate') {
                    return activate;
                }
                if (action === 'deactivate') {
                    return deactivate;
                }

                if (action === 'disable') {
                    return disable;
                }
                if (action === 'enable') {
                    return enable;
                }
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Funciones que se llaman al activar los botones

            function activate() // void
            {
                console.log('activate');
            }
            function deactivate() // void
            {
                console.log('deactivate');
            }
            function disable() // void
            {
                console.log('disable');
            }
            function enable() // void
            {
                console.log('enable');
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

**Este código funciona**.
Quisiera saber si puedo reemplazar `getCallbackFunc`. Trate de invocar diractamente la función *callback* reemplazando las líneas:

```
const action = buttonActions[index];
const selector = 'button[data-action="' + action + '"]';

const callback = getCallbackFunc(action);
const button = document.querySelector(selector)
    .addEventListener('click', callback);
```

por:

```
const action = buttonActions[index];
const selector = 'button[data-action="' + action + '"]';

const button = document.querySelector(selector)
    .addEventListener('click', action); // cambio aquí
```

Con un mensaje de error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'.

Volví a probar con:

```
const button = document.querySelector(selector)
    .addEventListener('click', new Object(action));
```

Sin errores, pero no funciona...
No se, si se entiende lo que estoy tratando de hacer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no he entendido mal, creo que la mejor idea es usar un objeto literal que almacene cada función asignada a una clave, en vez del array, de esta forma se puede instanciar las funciones como si se trataran de método:

```js
    window.onload = () => {
    'use strict';

    const buttonActions = {
        "activate": activate,
        "deactivate": deactivate,
        "disable": disable,
        "enable": enable,
    };

    Object.keys(buttonActions).forEach(m => {
        const selector = 'button[data-action="' + m + '"]';
        const button = document.querySelector(selector);
        button.addEventListener('click', buttonActions[m]);
        
    })

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Funciones que se llaman al activar los botones

    function activate() { console.log('activate'); }
    function deactivate() { console.log('deactivate'); }
    function disable() { console.log('disable'); }
    function enable() { console.log('enable'); }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main class="content">
        <h2>Prueba "callbacks"</h2>

        <section class="button-group right-content top-2">
            <h3 hidden>Botones de acción</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="activate">Activate</button>
            <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="deactivate">Deactivate</button>

            <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="disable">Disable</button>
            <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="enable">Enable</button>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

Usar un array tiene el inconveniente de que no sabes el nombre de la función, solamente la referencia a la función, de esta forma solo te puedes guiar por el índice.

Supongo que investigando, se podrá hacer los mismo con un mapa, pero no le encuentro el sentido.

Comment: Parece una solución bastante óptima y para el caso basta con difinir el objeto: `const buttonActions = {
activate,
deactivate,
disable,
enable,
};`

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que buscas solo necesitas usar [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) para hacer que tu string apunte al nombre de la función que tienes declarada en tu namespace. Con esta sencilla línea se resuelve tu problema:

```
const callback = eval(action);
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo haciendo esa sencilla modificación:

```js
window.onload = () => {
'use strict';

const buttonActions = [
    'activate',
    'deactivate',
    'disable',
    'enable',
];
for (let index = 0; index < buttonActions.length; index++) {
    const action = buttonActions[index];
    const selector = 'button[data-action="' + action + '"]';

    const callback = eval(action);
    const button = document.querySelector(selector)
        .addEventListener('click', callback);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Funciones que se llaman al activar los botones

function activate() // void
{
    console.log('activate');
}
function deactivate() // void
{
    console.log('deactivate');
}
function disable() // void
{
    console.log('disable');
}
function enable() // void
{
    console.log('enable');
}
};
```

```html
<main class="content">
    <h2>Prueba "callbacks"</h2>

    <section class="button-group right-content top-2">
        <h3 hidden>Botones de acción</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="activate">Activate</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="deactivate">Deactivate</button>

        <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="disable">Disable</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dafault" data-action="enable">Enable</button>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Usar `eval()` funciona tal y como esta planteada la pregunta, pero tiene asociado problemas de seguridad y no puede emplearse normalmente. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp?hl=es

Comment: @Orici los riesgos de seguridad en este caso no se aplican, ya que tu mismo estás generando los strings, no estás ejecutando código externo.

Comment: Lectura recomendada [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Comment: En el ejemplo usar `eval()` no es inseguro *per se* pero no es una solución que pueda aplicarse en una aplicación real donde existe una CSP definida que impide su ejecución: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#describiendo_una_pol%C3%ADtica

Comment: @Orici ninguna de esas políticas va a bloquearte un código que evalúa strings en tu propio namespace. Léelas bien. No obstante, es tu pregunta y es tu solución, así que seleccionas lo que más le convenga a tu aplicación. Mi respuesta es una forma de hacerlo, Creando las funciones en objetos es otra que también es muy buena, Haciendo bind de tus funciones al contexto actual y luego llamándolas con un string es otras. Toma la que se te ajuste, pero mi respuesta a lo que preguntas es correcta. Si puedes evitar usar eval, hazlo... pero No satanices la función.